# Chrome Issue with padding transition and fixed size

Tags: css, google-chrome, debugging

I just realized the item teasers on my website won't resize on-hover in Google Chrome.
I wrote it down to a Fiddle and found out it was the fixed size.

```
width: 120px;
height: 120px;
padding: 10px;
transition: padding 0.3s ease;
```

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/o63qjeo6/2/

It works in Safari and Firefox, but in Google Chrome only when you set, for example, height to "auto".

Does anyone have a workaround for this (except for setting a value to "auto") or a possible explanation to this bug?

I wonder why it works in Safari as both use Webkit.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have `box-sizing: border-box;` enabled.

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/o63qjeo6/3/)

Comment: Yeah, but I use box-sizing all over my page `* { box-sizing: border-box }`. Why does it work in any other browser?

Comment: Hmmm..intriguing. Different interpretations between browsers I guess. Images shouldn't really have *padding* though should they?...I'd imagine that's the issue. Not sure which browser is doing this right.